# getting response from php page to ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
   $instant_message=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `instant_estimate`.`message` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `mobile`, `message`,`updateddate`) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$email', '$mobile', '$message1','$date_str')");
    if($instant_message)
    {
        echo "1"; 
    }
```

**Ajax code**

```
  success:function(result)
       {

            if(result==1)
            {
                alert("Message has been sent");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error!");
            }
       }
```

even though im getting the response as 1,it goes for else part..why?

Comment: post ur entire ajax call

Comment: what you are getting when alert(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your code.. there something another issue, 
I think, `space` char might be come with AJAX response these character will not visible in ajax response but these can be such create issue, see below

You should check your server response properly and remove `space` or `enter` characters before Ajax response

PS: try this way on client side

```
"1 " == 1
//FALSE

"1 ".replace(/\s/, '') == 1
//TRUE
```

Comment: Hello!! Well said,i didnot find anything wrong in my code..As i refresh my page lot of time..it gives the response...Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: AJAX response will have to prefix or postfix invisible char e.g space enter, did you check that?

Comment: ya i have checked it.first time i have a <br> with the response.But after that <br> get removed.So that i got the answer it seems.But i did not do any changes with my previous file ji...

Answer (score -4):

What happens it that you're outputting a String and compairing with a number.
This:  `echo "1"`; is a string
`if(result==1)` you're waiting a number. You should change your if to:

```
if(result=="1")
```

Comment: "1" == 1 is also return TRUE

Comment: he does not uses `===`, so the error is somewhere else